# Eclipse - can't install google plugin for eclipse 4.3

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I've checked the - `.eclipseproduct` - file and it says that my version is `4.3.0`.

Now I've tried to install Google plugin for eclipse 4.3 - at the - `Help-->Install new software`. 
And I've used the `https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3` at the work with field.

Now when I choose the Google plugin it says that -

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43) requires 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I've even tried to install the google app engine but also it says that -

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
  Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Suite Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Suite Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 0.0.0
```

So what should I do in order to be able to install Google plugin for Eclipse 4.3?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the newest Eclipse, Eclipse Plugin and JDK. Maybe even update your JRE.

Otherwise try installing the whole [ADT-Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It's kind of an Eclipse IDE with the plugin preinstalled.

The last thing that comes to my mind is that you could try the [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that [ADT-Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) whose version is eclipse 4.2 has this issue of installing google plugin and when I downloaded eclipse and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) separately and connected them together. It solved the problem. Google plugin installation worked super fine then